# Which programs run on Windows IoT?

Tags: windows, cpu, raspberry-pi, arm, windows-iot-core

How do I know if TinyTask runs on Windows IoT on the Raspberry Pi 3? Its website says it's written in C but that doesn't say which CPU architecture it was made for. Is there maybe an app store for all Windows IoT ARM apps?

Comment: It’s important to differentiate: Windows IoT can refer to Windows 10 Enterprise (fully featured) or Windows 10 IoT Core (does not even have a shell). // Because Win 10 IoT Core does not have a shell, it is not comparable to regular Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I know if TinyTask runs on windows IoT on the raspberry pi 3?

The compiled version of [TinyTask](https://www.tinytask.net/index.php) on it's website is a x86 Windows executable.

> It's website says it's written in C but that doesn't answer for which
>   CPU architecture it was made.

**Just because it is written in C does not mean it can be modified to work on any operating system.** TinyTask is specifically designed to only work on Windows. If you had the source code, you might be able to recompile it to support ARM, but that isn't possible in the case of TinyTask.

> Is there maybe an application store for all Windows IoT applications?

Windows IoT UWP applications can indeed be found on the Windows Store but you cannot install the applications from within Windows IoT they must be preinstalled or installed via other means

> There is no support for Microsoft Store Client in IoT Core, i.e. you
>   cannot browse and install applications from an IoT Core device and all
>   required apps must be preinstalled or installed via other means such
>   as OMA-DM/Azure DM.

[Microsoft Store support for IoT Core UWP Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/commercialize-your-device/installingandservicing)